# Importing sqlite db using sqlite porter plugin in json format with column type

Tags: sqlite, ionic4

How can we specify the columns type in the json that we use to import data to cordova sqlite?
Currently the json is as follows

{
   "structure":{
       "tables":{
           "technologies":"([id] PRIMARY KEY, [name], [description])"
       }
   },
   "data":{
      "inserts": {
         "technologies": [
            {"id":1,"name":"Angular","description":"Front-end development framwork created by Google"},
            {"id":2,"name":"TypeScript","description":"Superset of JavaScript"},
            {"id":3,"name":"HTML5","description":"A collection of different JavaScript API's and new HTML markup syntax"},
            {"id":4,"name":"Sass","description":"CSS Pre-processor for writing stylesheets with a programmatic approach"},
            {"id":5,"name":"Apache Cordova","description":"Hybrid application development framework"}
         ]
      }
   }
}

I want to create table with id as number and name, description as text
Is that possible?

Comment: Outside of an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, column types are mostly just hints about the preferred storage format. You don't really need them with sqlite.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn. So for varchar, are we going to add text or varchar(20) etc? And what should we add for timestamp?

Comment: You don't *have* to have anything but a column name. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for what types in a column definition do in sqlite.

Comment: Though when using types, I just stick with the core sqlite ones - text, real, etc. to avoid confusing someone not familiar with the database who is wondering why, say, varchar(20) is holding a string a few hundred characters long.